# How to auto adjust height of div when working with dual Monitors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there is any way of achieving this without refreshing the page. I code on a 27 inch monitor and see the result in 15 inch monitor. When I move the result to 27 inch monitor, it stays the same until I refresh the page.

```js
var hgt = $(window).height();
$('#mydiv').height(hgt);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <link rel="favicon" href="images.png">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div style="border:1px solid black" id="mydiv">
        some content
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe you want to look into responsiveness and bootstrap.

Comment: is the result the same when you using something like flexbox?

Comment: @OneNeptune I have not used flexbox. I will update you after using flexbox.

Comment: @pid We are not using any library. I used jquery in the above example because asking question would become easier for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is to skip javascript and do this all with html/css

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#mydiv{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <link rel="favicon" href="images.png">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div style="border:1px solid black" id="mydiv">
        some content
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is much cleaner solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resize` browser event to know when your window is resized.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {   
    var hgt = $(window).height();   
    $('#mydiv').height(hgt); 
});
```